# Eclipse editor doesn't recognize Scipy content

Tags: python, eclipse, scipy

I just installed Scipy and Numpy on my machine and added them to the System Library option in eclipse.

Now the program runs fine, but eclipse editor keeps giving this red mark on the side says "Unresolved import".

I guess I didn't configure correctly.

Any one know how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved. Just add to the forced buildins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to recreate your project in PyDev and add these new libraries.